# Unable to read data from rs232 port using java

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication

I have an application that enables me to connect my laptop to a GPS receiver and communicate with it.
The connection is made using simple serial port connection.
The method that creates the connection looks like that:

```
public void openport(){
        try {   
            String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String file = dir+"/Some/Directory/blabla.txt;
            File F = new File(file);
            if (!F.getParentFile().exists()){
                F.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(F));
            SP.openPort();
            SP.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            SP.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader(),SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR); 
        } 
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {msgArea.append(ex.toString() + "\n");} 
        catch (IOException ex) {msgArea.append(ex.toString() + "\n");}
    }
```

The event listener class looks like that:

```
class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
        String tmp = "";

        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {         
                try {
                    tmp += SP.readString();
                    if (tmp.contains("\n") && tmp.length() > 2){
                            if (tmp.contains("$GPGGA") && tmp.length() > 60){
                                decompose_GPGGA(tmp);
                            } else if (tmp.contains("$GPGLL")&& tmp.length() > 20){
                                decompose_GPGLL(tmp);
                            } else if (tmp.contains("$GPGSA") && tmp.length() > 14){
                                decompose_GPGSA(tmp);
                            } else if (tmp.contains("$GPGRS") && tmp.length() > 14){
                                int ind = tmp.indexOf("$GPGRS");
                                String str = tmp.substring(ind);
                                decompose_GPGRS(str);
                            }
                        tmp = "";
                    }
                } 
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {msgArea.append(ex.toString() + "\n");} 
            }
        }}
```

Using the listener class I read messages that are coming out of the receiver and decode them.

The problem is that when the connection is made from usb to usb it works perfectly. However, when the connection is from usb to RS232 I am not able to read any incoming data. 
The connection no the laptop is always USB port, on the receiver I have two connection options (USB or RS232).

Why is this happening? Am i doing something wrong? should i use a different approach for the connection? 
Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Edited. As i said, when the connection is USB <--> USB it works fine. When the connection is USB <--> RS232 it does not.

Comment: What package are you using that provides the SP class?

Comment: It is a serial port instance from JSSC.

Comment: I would add that to your question.  It's critical information.  I'd try various different baud-rates and other settings to see if it works.  Also are you getting any events?  If not then you may to refer to their docs to see what's going on.